# Arrow with color gradient in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to make arrows in matplotlib where the color of the arrow is changing gradually from one color to another?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible out of the box, but it's probably hackable.

- For a start, have a look at [This example that shows how to do a gradient line](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multicolored_line.html)
- or [This example to draw a gradient bar](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/gradient_bar.html)

depending on what kind of arrow you want to draw.